# Secure endpoint with id in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a question about spring security. Let's say that I have endpoint like this

```
 /orders/order/{userId}
```

How to prevent from the situation when I have multiple logged users and someone could type userId of the other logged user. For example

*User_1* have `id = 1`,

*User_2* have `id = 2`

and now User_2 could just put the id of User_1 and retrieve his orders or delete it. Should I just check for each request if the id from URL is equal to the current logged user or there are better ways to do that with spring security?. The same scenario will be when I use username in URL pattern instead user id, e.g.

```
 /orders/order/{username}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the user logged in using their credential we normally generate the unique token for it and send it to the client. Then the client sends that token for further requests to validate the user on the server-side. You can create and use Utils class for generating the token and validating the user. When the user makes the request at `/orders/order/{userId}` fetch the userId and map it with the userId from token. If it is valid then perform the required actions or give response `401/403` (I am taking an example of JWT Token here)

```
public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
     return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject);
} 

 public String generateToken(User user) {
     return doGenerateToken(user.getEmail() , user.getRole());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any kind of authentification?
Once a user is logged in you could handle his/her id with a token (JWT for example) and match the id in the URL with the one encoded in your token although at that point the ID in the URL becomes useless.

Comment: Yes I have authentication based on JWT. So I should store user id in token and then when I authenticate speciffic user I should compare encoded id with id from the url request?

Comment: As Ronald Hund wrote: if you pass JWT token, then there is no need to send user id in url